# Как вывести иерархический запрос в одной строке?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, hierarchy

Пробую выполнить запрос:

```sql
SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(surname, '/') Tree
FROM viewdb
START WITH surname = 'Mayhem'
CONNECT BY PRIOR code = code_boss;
```

Результат:

```
/Mayhem /Henderson
/Mayhem /Diamond
```

А как его вывести в одной строке ?

Например:

```
/Mayhem /Henderson /Diamond
```

Можно ли это сделать, например, с помощью `SUBSTR()` и `DECODE()`?
Если да, то как взять 1-ый результат и сравнивать его с новым?

---

Доп.инф.:
Henderson и Diamond являются наследниками Mayhem. Остальные не интересуют. Нужно только теx, кто находится в подчинении Mayhem, так сказать. У меня получилось вывести в одну строку с помощью `MAX()`, но он все равно выводит `/Mayhem /Henderson`, `Diamond` не включает

Comment: Это зависит от содержимого вашей таблицы. судя по запросу у вас там /Diamind не является наследником /Henderson. Так что к иерархическим запросам ваше требования в выводе и структуре входных данных никакого отношения не имеет

Comment: То есть никак нельзя вывести всех наследников Mayhem в одну строку ?

Comment: Можно, но способ вывода будет зависеть от того, кто же чей наследник. А этого вы в вопросе не указали

Comment: Наследники только прямые нужны ? тогда просто join и собирать чем нибудь вроде listagg(). Если всех уровней то так же connect by, только выводить сами значения, скорее всего обернуть еще в один запрос (хотя может и не надо) и опять же применить listagg()

Answer (score 2):

Построить лист непосредственных подчинённых для каждого менеджера, затем соединить со служебной лестницей соответсвующего менеджера. На примере схемы HR, вот так:

```sql
with h1 as (
    select 
        sys_connect_by_path (e.last_name, '/') path, 
        e.last_name, level lvl, connect_by_isleaf isleaf, employee_id, e.manager_id
    from hr.employees e
    connect by manager_id = prior employee_id
    start with manager_id is null)
select path||'/'||subordinates subordinatesByPath  
from h1
join ( 
    select 
        manager_id, listagg (last_name, ';') within group (order by manager_id) subordinates 
    from h1
    group by manager_id) m on m.manager_id = h1.employee_id  
order by employee_id
/
```

Даст желаемый результат (укорочен):

```
subordinatesByPath
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
/King/Cambrault;De Haan;Errazuriz;Fripp;Hartstein;Kaufling;Kochhar;Mourgos;
Partners;Raphaely;Russell;Vollman;Weiss;Zlotkey
/King/Kochhar/Baer;Greenberg;Higgins;Mavris;Whalen
/King/De Haan/Hunold
```